# Date format in PHP or Laravel 5 sending a parameter lang

Tags: php, date, laravel, laravel-5, date-format

I receive the date parameter of my database with this format:

```
"date" => "2015/08/11T00:00:00Z"
```

I need get the right date format sending a locale (in Laravel App::getLocale()) parameter.

Something like this:

```
<? date_format_magicfunction($my_date, 'es' ); ?> // 11/08/2015
```

or

```
                                        //es, en, de, etc   
 <? date_format_magicfunction($my_date, App::getLocale() ); ?> // 11/08/2015
```

Do you know some function or Laravel Provider?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you can create a date using DateTime [DateTime::createFromFormat ()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) from any format as log as you specify it as it is indicated on the API. Note the returned value from this function is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon package. http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting It contains lots of methods to manipulate datetime objects.